# link_to in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

```
<%= link_to_remote "See more", :url => { :action => "activity", :page_current => (@page_current.to_i + 1), :user_id=>@suser_profile.id }, :update => "sup_activity_#{@page_current.to_s}", :position => :before %>
```

how to convert this to link with the remote=>true in rails 3

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't this work?

```
<%= link_to "See more", :url => { :action => "activity", :page_current => (@page_current.to_i + 1), :user_id=>@suser_profile.id }, :update => "sup_activity_#{@page_current.to_s}", :position => :before, :remote => true %>
```

Comment: Missing the , between :before and :remote !